# Complexity of this variant of $positive -⊕2SAT$?

Tags: complexity-theory, 2-sat

This is like a follow up question from my previous post about complexity of $positive -⊕2SAT$.

The problem positive $⊕2SAT$ is defined as a problem where we need to find the parity of the number of solutions of positive $2$-$CNF$ formulae and is known to be $\oplus P$ complete.

I introduce the following variant of $⊕2SAT$:

In this variant we put the restriction on the input of the positive $⊕2SAT$ problem the restriction is that every input must contain all clauses that contain a specific variable ,for concretness ,let's say we put the restriction on the input such that every input must contain all positive 2-literal clauses that contains variable (a) .

I want to ask if this variant remains $\oplus P$ complete.

I think this variant is $\oplus P$ complete ,my reasons are that the output of this type of problem is restricted to either true or false thus ,I think even if we apply the above restriction the input should be able to express any positive $⊕2SAT$ instance.

Comment: I suggest you spend some more time trying to work out the answer for yourself.  I already gave you some feedback on your last paragraph: https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/159087/755.  I suggest you try to work out the details of the reduction more carefully.  I also suggest spend some time trying to find a polynomial-time algorithm, and try to work with a few examples to see if you could find a way to do that (and if not, what the barriers are).

Comment: I would just like to know the complexity status of this problem ,I am happy to find reduction myself and just to clarify if the general positive−⊕2SAT is ⊕P-complete ?

Comment: @D.W. I have tried forming a intersection graph that shows Which clause intersects which clause and then to find the parity of the set of clause, I have tried to check if the number of path from each clause to every other clause is odd or not but,- this method is not polynomial and every other way I've tried are just variations of the above method .I haven't been able to find a polynomial-.time algorithm in past 2 days . Would really appreciate any help regarding the post .

Comment: Problems that came during finding algorithm is mainly the intersections between the clauses , It's the only barrier according to me,.